# Executing commands based off user input a certain number of times

Tags: bash, scripts

Hello everyone and thank you for any future help, I am a little new to bash as a warning.

I am trying to configure /etc/host information based off a user input. So far I have this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "How many servers do you want to configure"
read var1
echo $var1
```

Then based off the number entered by the user, run a number of echos to populate my /etc/host file.
echo "ipaddress slavehostname >> /etc/hosts

Then later change the  and  using a series of sed commands.

However I am drawing a blank on how to get the user input to drive number of times to run the echoing.

Any ideas on a way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a `for` or `while` loop in bash?

Comment: I am familiar with for and while loops, I am asking how would the value of var1 would be utilized to execute a series of echos into /etc/hosts. As I think just doing a for i in $var1 would only be able to echo the number of $var1 into /etc/hosts rather then executing a series of commands a certain number of times.

Comment: ... so maybe you are looking for something like `for i in $(seq 1 "$var1")`; do ...`